# Constraint Layout SPREAD and PACKED combination

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I want to create following `ConstraintLayout`:

[image]

In other words, I want to have a chain, where all elements are **spread** and only second and third ones are **packed**. I can do that by removing *third element* from the chain and apply the following code to it:

`app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/second_element"`

it works as expected.

**BUT**

In case of small device, where this chain is pushed together, *third element* would be above the *fourth element*. Like this:

[image]

In that case, I need to have it evenly positioned:

[image]

Thank you for every help.

Comment: Handling this programmatically is probably the easiest way. Can you make any assumptions about the height of the views? Are they all the same? Are they all of a defined specific height?

Comment: Yes, they are all of defined specific height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by extracting 2nd and 3rd items to separate layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout ... >

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/second"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      ...
      />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/third"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/second"
      ...
      />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And by including it in the main layout. This included layout would replace 2nd and 3rd element. By adding it to vertical chain, all works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonOne"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttonTwo"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonTwo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttonThree"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/buttonOne" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonThree"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttonFour"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/buttonTwo" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonFour"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttonFive"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/buttonThree" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonFive"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/buttonFour" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Using `bias` the way you did will move all the elements to the top of the screen. So in bigger screens, it would be on the top, I need them to be spread.

Comment: use scrollLayout as a parent layout so, in small device you can scroll the layout till bottom

Answer (score 0):

Views two and three could be wrapped into their own view group and the view group would participate in the chain. This will work, but the gap between those two views would be constant and may look odd on a small screen if that spacing looks larger than the other spacing.

Another approach is to remove the third element from the chain, as you have mentioned, but to look for an overlap between the third and fourth elements. When there is an overlap, the chain can be modified to include all the elements in a packed chain arrangement. The code to do this would look something like this:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val constraintLayout = findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.mainLayout)
        constraintLayout.doOnLayout {
            val tv3 = findViewById<View>(R.id.textView3)
            val tv4 = findViewById<View>(R.id.textView4)
            if (tv4.top < tv3.bottom) {
                val constraintSet = ConstraintSet()
                constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout)
                constraintSet.createVerticalChain(
                    ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,
                    ConstraintSet.TOP,
                    ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,
                    ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,
                    intArrayOf(
                        R.id.textView1,
                        R.id.textView2,
                        R.id.textView3,
                        R.id.textView4,
                        R.id.textView5
                    ),
                    null,
                    ConstraintSet.CHAIN_SPREAD
                )
                constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**I Hope this code may help you, it is responsive in all devices screen size. If you find correct answer then please correct it.**

**activity_man.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout          

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Activity_Camera">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/first_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="#03A9F4"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="1"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.20" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/secon_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#F44336"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="2"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/first_id"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/third_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="#FF5722"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="3"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.50"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/secon_id"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/four_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#8BC34A"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="4"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.50"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/third_id"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/five_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#673AB7"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="5"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.50"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/four_id"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```